# Auto importing modules in the folder and allowing them to be selected by name from a variable string

Tags: python-3.x

## How it's organized

Currently, this is my folder structure:

```
├   Websites
│   ├   Prototypes
│   │   ├   __init__.py
│   │   ├   Website.py
│   │   └   XML.py
│   ├   __init__.py
│   └   FunHouse.py
└   scrape_sites.py
```

This is `FunHouse.py`:

```
from Websites.Prototypes.Website import Website, Search

class FunHouse(Website):
    def doStuff():
    # does stuff
```

This is my `__init__.py` in the Websites folder:

```
from Websites.Prototypes.Website import Website
from Websites.FunHouse import FunHouse


def choose_site(website):
    if website == "FunHouse":
        return FunHouse()
    else:
        return Website()
```

And in my `scrape_sites.py` file is the following:

```
import Websites

# Some code that loads a text file and sets website_string to "FunHouse"
website = Websites.choose_site(website_string)
website.doStuff()
```

## My Question

If I want to add a website, I have to edit `__init__.py`. Is there any way to make it so that I don't have to edit the `__init__.py` file whenever I add a new website? So if I create `Google.py`, I can just throw it into the Websites folder and it will be available to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't even need the `__init__.py` files:

```
def choose_site(website_str):
    mod = __import__('Websites.' + website_str, fromlist=[website_str])
    obj = getattr(mod, website_str)
    return obj()
```

This relies on the class name being the same as the Python filename, because if you pass in "Google" in the argument, it will import `Websites.Google.Google`

If you're looking at this and wanted to have more flexibility, this will work:

```
def choose_class(module_name, filename, class_name):
    """

    :param module_name: The folder
    :param filename: The .py file
    :param class_name: The class in the .py file
    :return: The selected class
    """
    mod = __import__(module_name+ '.' + filename, fromlist=[filename])
    obj = getattr(mod, class_name)
    return obj()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `__all__` variable to your `__init__.py` file once.

```
__all__ = ["Google", "Yahoo", "Bing"]
```

Now, each of these modules will be available to you in your code to use.